# What is a good way of saying "run this after 15 minutes" on a shell?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sleep

I use this

```
sleep 900; <command>
```

on my shell. Just wanted to know is there is some alternate/better way that you use?

Comment: you can do `sleep 15m && command`, that way if you want to cancel it you can `ctrl-c` it (your version would run the command if you `ctrl-c` it).

Comment: @OneOfOne I don't know if it's shell or something else dependent, but I've never seen Ctrl+C fallthrough like that; it cancels the entire line

Comment: @Michael I coulda swore it used to do that with older bash, I just tried and it didn't, so ignore my comment

Comment: @OneOfOne: It did up to bash 3.x; that's fixed in bash 4.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are searching for `at` ([at@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29))?

```
usr@srv % at now + 15 min
at> YOUR COMMAND HERE
```

You can define multiple commands that should be executed in 15 min; separate them with a return.
Confirm all commands with `control+d`.

Answer (score 4):

I use a short script I keep in my path, called *after*, containing

```
at now + "$@"
```

This way it's very easy to, for example, type:

```
after 15 min
```

then any commands and Ctrl-D, or

```
echo COMMANDS | after 15 min
```

which does the same.

Comment: you might want to use `"$@"` instead of `$*` -- then arguments containing spaces will be properly quoted

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited my answer accordingly. I think it doesn't change anything in the context of the _at_ command, bu it's definitely better standard practice.

Comment: you need to use the quotes around it: specifically `"$@"` not `$@`. Only when quoted will bash perform this special expansion: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: @glenn, re-edited accordingly. Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that!